# Count numbers between a range in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

a = 5 and b = 8

I need to use these numbers in for loop.

```
for i in range(a, b):
```

These will start from 5 to 8

If i use like below

```
for i in (a, b):
```

These will print 5 and 8.

Now i need a help from you, if a = 5 and 8 means i need find the the range between 5 to 8 is 1 to 4 and   form for loop 1 to 4

if a = 3 and 5 means i need find the the range between 3 to 5 is 1 to 3 and  form for loop 1 to 3 .

Comment: I think hes asking for values of i to range from 0 to the difference between the numbers.

Comment: for what you have described in your question i think youre solution would look something like this `for i in range(a,(b+1))`

Comment: Whats The Point of using range(a,(b+1)) according to my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`range(a, b)` returns a list of `b - a` values, while `(a, b)` is a tuple with only two values.

To solve your problem you could do e.g.

```
for x in range(a, b + 1):  # +1 to include the end of the range in the list
    x = x - a + 1;  # Make x start at 1
    ...
```

Or

```
for x in range(1, b - a + 2):  # +1 to include end of range, +1 again since range start at 1
    ...
```

Or (as noted by DeepSpace)

```
for x in range(b - a + 1):  # +1 to include the end of the range
    x = x + 1  # Since range should start at 1
    ...
```

Comment: `range(b - a)` is a much simpler alternative (or `range(1, b - a + 1)` to include both 1 and `b - a`)

Comment: Thanks a lot sir I used for x in range(a, b) and x = x-a +1;. It gives solution

Comment: @DeepSpace : that will start from `0`

Comment: @Jahid There is an *or* part to my comment.

Comment: @DeepSpace : `range(1, b - a + 1)` needs to be `range(1, b - a + 2)`, otherwise it's wrong too, according to OP's requirement, that is.

Answer (score 1):

```
for count, value in enumerate(range(a, b), 1):
    print(count)
```